# Optimal strategy for a 3 players infinite game

Tags: game-theory

I've been asked the following game theory problem:

> Each one of three players secretly picks a positive integer.
>   The winner of the game, if any, is the player who picked the smallest
>   number that no one else chose.

Is there an optimal strategy for this game?

**Observations** Nash' theorem about the existence of an equilibrium doesn't apply to this game, because each player has infinitely many possible choices.

A way I thought to tackle the problem is the following. *I assume the existence of an optimal strategy*, and I model it by a function $f: \mathbb{Z}_{>0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) =1$, which corresponds to picking $n$ with probability $f(n)$. Then, since the strategy is optimal, every player is playing according to this strategy, and the probability $p_f(n)$ that a player wins playing $n$ is given by

$$p_f(n) = f(n) \left(\left(\sum_{m=n+1}^\infty f(m) \right)^2 + \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} f(m)^2 \right).$$

Where $f(n)$ is the probability that she plays $n$, $\left(\sum_{m=n+1}^\infty f(m) \right)^2$ is the probability that both the other players play a number larger than $n$ and $\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} f(m)^2$ is the probability that both the other players play the same number smaller than $n$.

Now we want to maximize the probability of a player winning, i.e.
$$p_f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) \left(\left(\sum_{m=n+1}^\infty f(m) \right)^2 + \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} f(m)^2 \right).$$

I'm a bit at a loss on how to proceed here. If we make the *reasonable* choice $f(n) = 2^{-n}$, then $p_f = \frac{2}{7}$. This doesn't seem too bad, but it's not optimal. Indeed if two players play this strategy and the third plays the pure strategy $N\geq 2$, she increases her chances to win.

On the other hand the strategy given by
$$f_N(n) =\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{N}, & \text{ for }n\leq N \\
0, & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases} $$ 
is such that $p_{f_N} \rightarrow \frac{1}{3}$ for $N\rightarrow \infty$. But it is clearly very far from being optimal.

I'm grateful for any answer, suggestion or comment.

Comment: How can $p_f = \frac{2}7$ if all the players are symmetric ?

Comment: I don't see the issue. I'm just saying that if everybody plays this strategy then the probability of each player to win is $\frac{2}{7}$, and the probability that no one wins, i.e. all of them choose the same number, is $1-3\cdot \frac{2}{7} = \frac{1}{7} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-3n}$. But, since I'm a total beginner of game theory, I could be saying rubbish.

Comment: To clarify: If two players pick $1$ and the third player picks $2$, does the third player win or does noone win?

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano: Thanks for your clarification. Sorry, I am a beginner in game theory too. Can you clarify how you got that expression for $p_f(n)?$

Comment: @smcc Thanks for your question. In the case you describe the third player would win. Sandeep, I edit the question immediately to make it clearer!

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano:Thanks! Thats a lot more clear!

Comment: My experimental results tell me that $f(k)=a\cdot d^{k-1}$ where $\frac{a}{d-1} = 1$ and $d$ is a root of $d^4-2d+1 = 0$ around $0.543$ (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5E4-2d%2B1+%3D+0)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In game theorey the players are selfish, i.e. the probability of winning that we want to maximize is:

$$p(f,g,h) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n) \Bigg(\bigg(\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} g(k) \bigg)\bigg(\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} h(k) \bigg) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} g(k)\cdot h(k) \Bigg),\tag{$\spadesuit$}$$

where $f$, $g$ and $h$ are probability distributions for the first, second and third player respectively. In fact what we want is that $f = g = h$, but that is not true when considering *individual* optimizations from the player perspective (i.e. the conditions for a Nash Equilibrium).

Now, fix some arbitrary functions $f_1, g_1, h_1$ and observe that if $\frac{\partial p}{\partial f(i)}(f_1,g_1,h_1) < \frac{\partial p}{\partial f(j)}(f_1,g_1,h_1)$ then there exists a tiny strictly positive amount $\delta$ of probability mass that we could shift from number $i$ to number $j$, i.e. take

$$f_2(k) = 
\begin{cases}
f_1(k)-\delta & \text{ when }k = i\\
f_1(k)+\delta & \text{ when }k = j\\
f_1(k) & \text{ otherwise},
\end{cases}$$

and strictly increase the value of $p$, i.e. $p(f_1,g_1,h_1) < p(f_2,g_1,h_1)$.
Thus, at a Nash Equilibrium $(f,g,h)$ we have to have $\frac{\partial p}{\partial f(i)}(f,g,h) = \frac{\partial p}{\partial f(j)}(f,g,h)$ for any $i$ and $j$.

Fortunately $(\spadesuit)$ gives us a nice formula for that. Adding our requirement for an optimal strategy that $f = g = h$ we get $q_i = q_j$ where ($q_n$ was intentionally kept to be consistent with answer of @smcc):

\begin{align}
q_n
  &= \frac{\partial p}{\partial f(n)}(f,g,h)\ \Bigg|_{g = h = f} \\
  &= \bigg(\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} g(k) \bigg)\bigg(\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} h(k) \bigg) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} g(k)\cdot h(k)\ \Bigg|_{g = h = f} \\
  &= \bigg(\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} f(k) \bigg)^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f^2(k) \\
  &= \bigg(1-\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k) \bigg)^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f^2(k).
\end{align}

I cannot prove that this is the unique equilibrium, but we can show that there exist one particular, namely $f(n) = (1-d)\cdot d^{n-1}$ where $d$ denotes the probability of *not* picking number $1$ and it happens to be the only real root of $d^3+d^2+d^1 - 1 = 0$.

With that hypothesis we have that

\begin{align}
q_n 
  &= \bigg(1-\sum_{k=1}^{n} (1-d)\cdot d^{k-1} \bigg)^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \big((1-d)\cdot d^{k-1}\big)^2 \\
  &= d^{2n} + \frac{(1-d)(d^2-d^{2n})}{(1+d)d^2} = \frac{(1-d)d^2+d^{2n} \overbrace{(d^3+d^2+d-1)}^{\text{zero}}}{(1+d)d^2} = \frac{1-d}{1+d}
\end{align}

Thus, all the $q_n$'s are constant and so $(f,f,f)$ is a Nash Equilibrium.
[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5E3%2Bd%5E2%2Bd%5E1-1+%3D+0) says

$$d = \frac13\left(\sqrt[3]{17+3\sqrt{33}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{17+3 \sqrt{33}}}-1\right) \approx 0.543689.$$

On a final note, equation $d^3+d^2+d^1 = 1$ or perhaps better $$\big(1-f(1)\big)^3+\big(1-f(1)\big)^2+\big(1-f(1)\big)^1 = 1$$ suggest that $f$ satisfies $f(n) = f(n+1) + f(n+2) + f(n+3)$ (like a reversed 3-term Fibonacci sequence), but I can't find any probabilistic interpretation for that. Maybe someone can use it to obtain a nice elegant proof?

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, +1! There are a few points that are still unclear to me. 1) I see *a posteriori* that $$q_n = \frac{\partial p}{\partial f(n)}(f,g,h)\big|_{g=h=f},$$
because we can compute $q_n$ from the definition given by smcc. But I do not see why is this *a priori* true. 2) How did you deduce your particular strategy $f(n) = (1-d)d^{n-1}$ with $d$ being the only real root of $d^3+d^2+d-1=0$? Thanks again!

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano 2) Experiments, see my previous comment at your post. 1) My definition of $q_n$ is different: it is the marginal gain in winning probability if we were to play $n$ more often, and I give a separate reason why all of them have to be equal. It just so happens (and not by coincidence but that is irrelevant) that the formulas for both mine and smcc's $q_n$'s are the same.

Answer (score 2):

First note that there are infinitely many pure strategy Nash equilibria where one player plays $1$, and the other players each choose some larger integer(s). There is no incentive to deviate  because the players with  integers larger than $1$ cannot win.

Similarly there are infinitely many Nash equilibria where one player plays $1$ and the other players mix over larger integers in any way.

There are also three equilibria where two players play $1$ and the third plays $2$.

---

Let us look for a symmetric equilibrium where players play all positive integers with positive probability. Let $p_i$ denote the probability of playing $i$. It must be that (given the mixed strategy  the others are  playing) the probability of winning from playing any integer with probability one is the same.

If a player plays $n$ they win with probability

$$q_n=\left(\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty p_i \right)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} p_i^2 .$$

Since $$\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty p_i=1-\sum_{i=1}^np_i$$ we can write this as

$$q_n=\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^n p_i\right)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} p_i^2.$$

---

We require $q_n=\frac{1}{3}k^2$ for all  positive integers $n$, where $k^2$ is the probability (given the players' common strategy) that there is a winner, i.e.

$$k^2=1-\sum_{i=1}^\infty p_i^3.$$

---

When $n=1$ we have

$$q_1=(1-p_1)^2=\frac{1}{3}k^2$$

so $p_1=1-\frac{k}{\sqrt{3}}$.

When $n=2$ we have

$$q_2=(1-p_1-p_2)^2+p_1^2=\frac{1}{3}k^2$$

so $p_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(k-\sqrt{2\sqrt{3}k-3}\right)$.

Continuing, in this way one can solve recursively for each $p_i$ as a function of $k^2$ and then calculate $k^2$.

---

Note that there cannot be a symmetric equilibrium where they play only integers up to $n$ with positive probability, because a player would have a higher probability of winning from playing $n+1$  than playing $n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm actually puzzled by the assumption $q_n=\frac{1}{3}$, which I don't understand. Moreover your numbers do not give an optimal strategy, indeed assume that two players play your strategy and the third plays always $2$. Then she wins with probability:
$$p_1^2 + \left( \sum_{n=3}^\infty p_n\right)^2 > (0.4)^2 + (1-p_1-p_2)^2> (0.4)^2 + (0.45)^2 = \frac{29}{80}>\frac{1}{3}.$$

Perhaps it is just a calculation mistake. Could you please clarify the proof? Thanks!

Comment: The probabilities are chosen so that the probability of winning by playing any given integer (with probability one) is the same, i.e. $q_1=q_2=\cdots$ (this is a standard condition for a mixed strategy to be part of a NE). This must be true, otherwise a player would be better off deviating to play only those strategies with the highest probability of winning. We need $q_n=1/3$ for all $n$ because there are three players playing the same mixed strategy and so having equal chance of winning. I am not sure what you are doing with your calculation, but $q_2=q_n$ for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: @smcc $q_n\neq 1/3$, as there is a non-zero probability (i.e. $p_n^3$) that nobody wins.

Comment: At the light of dtldarek's answer I understand your crucial observation: *It must be that (...) the probability of winning from playing any integer with probability one is the same*. Thanks for it and +1!

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano I added a bit to my answer: there are infinitely many asymmetric pure strategy Nash equilibria (which were very easy to find!)