# Lowest Unique Ordinal Game

Tags: game-theory, ordinals, nash-equilibrium

The "lowest unique integer game" is widely-known: Some number of players each pick an integer from the range $[1, n]$ and the winner is the player who chose the lowest unique integer (if such a player exists; otherwise, the game is a tie). People have also considered the version where there is no upper bound on the set of integers you can choose from. (I first saw it in [this](http://www.quantopia.net/interview-questions-v-the-lowest-unique-positive-integer-game/) blog, but that page is no longer available. It was also considered in [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13061/guessing-the-smallest-unique-positive-integer) CS.SE post and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895076/optimal-strategy-for-a-3-players-infinite-game) Math.SE post.) I am interested in what happens if we play this game on an ordinal $\alpha$. That is, each player chooses an ordinal in the range $[1, \alpha)$ and the winner is the player that chose the smallest ordinal. (It seems traditional to start with $1$ instead of $0$ in this game.)

For the rest of this post, let's limit the number of players to $3$. In this case, the game on $\omega$ has a symmetric mixed strategy Nash equilibrium where each player picks the integer $k$ with probability $p_k = (1-x)x^{k-1}$ where $x$ is the real root of $x^3 + x^2 + x - 1 = 0$ (which also happens to be the Tribonacci constant!).

Here is the sketch: Assume that two of the players are playing with the same (mixed) strategy where they choose $i$ with probability $p_i$. Then if the third player chooses $k$, she wins if either both other players chose something larger than $k$ or if they chose the same integer less than $k$. That is, the probability that player 3 wins given that she chooses $k$ is

\begin{equation}\tag{*}
\left(1 - \sum_{i=1}^{k} p_i\right)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} p_i^2.
\end{equation}

In order for this to be at equilibrium, these should be the constant as $k$ varies. Then, one just checks that $p_k = (1-x)x^{k-1}$ makes this true and satisfies that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty p_i = 1$.

Now let's consider the game on $\omega + 1$. This is the same as the above except now players can choose $\omega$ as well. Let's say that players 1 and 2 do this with probability $p_\omega$. Then the probability that player 3 wins by choosing the integer $k$ is just (*), and the probability that she wins choosing $\omega$ is just the probability that the other two players choose the same integer, which is $\sum_{i=1}^\infty p_i^2$. But this is just the limit as $k$ approaches $\infty$ of (*), which means that the previous equilibrium (along with $p_\omega = 0$) is an equilibrium for the game on $\omega+1$ as well.

My questions are:

> 1. Is there a Nash equilibrium for the game on $\omega + 1$ where $p_\omega$ is nonzero? What about a non-symmetric equilibrium? Clearly, it's not categorically irrational for a player to pick $\omega$: If two players are playing with the strategy above then the third player will have the same probability of winning if she picks $\omega$ as if she picks $1$.
> 2. Is this Nash Equilibrium unique? One can show that it is unique for the finite ordinals. What about for the infinite game?
> 3. What about for larger countable ordinals? For example,  $\omega + 10$ or $\omega \cdot 2$?

Some thoughts on question 1: I have a feeling the answer should be "no", but I'm not sure how to prove it. I've tried to find a strategy for the game on $\omega + 1$ of the same kind of exponential form $p_k = Ax^{k-1}, p_\omega = c$ but I keep running into obstructions when $c \neq 0$.

Another thing to notice is that the equations (*) imply that the sequence $\{p_1, p_2, \ldots\}$ is non-increasing. Indeed, comparing equation $k$ with equation $k+1$ we can rearrange to get $p_k^2 - p_{k+1}^2$ on one side where the other side is apparently nonnegative. But I can't seem to find a way to argue that $p_k \geq p_\omega$ for all $k$ (which would imply $p_\omega = 0$ as $\sum_{i=1}^\omega p_i = 1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think question 1 finds the root of the problem.  When you consider the game on $\omega+1$ you need to define a new variable $p_\omega$ for the chance a player plays $\omega$.  Your expression for the chance of winning for any finite ordinal is still correct but the sum of the $p_i$ for $i$ finite is now $1-p_\omega$.  The chance of winning if you choose $\omega$ is $$ \sum_{i\lt \omega}p_i^2$$
For a given value of $p_\omega$ the argument for the $\omega$ strategy  goes through nicely and one should choose $k$ with probability $(1-x)x^{k-1}(1-p_\omega)$  We can now find $p_\omega$ by claiming it should have the same chance of winning as if you choose $1$, so 
$$ \sum_{i\lt \omega}p_i^2=(1-p_1)^2\\
 \sum_{i\lt \omega}\left((1-x)x^{k-1}(1-p_\omega)\right)^2=\left((1-x)(1-p_\omega)\right)^2$$
If we assume $p_\omega \gt 0$, we can find a $k$ such that $p_k \lt p_\omega$.  Then the chance you will be tied choosing $k$ will be less than the chance you will be tied choosing $\omega$.  If you are not tied at $k$, you will win all the time you would have won with $\omega$ and some more because the others could choose higher numbers.  This means choosing $k$ dominates over choosing $\omega$.  This says the $\omega+1$ strategy is the same as the $\omega$ strategy.  I then believe this carries over to all higher ordinals.

Comment: Could you expand on your first point a little more? I'm having a hard time seeing it. I don't think that picking $\omega$ and picking $1$ have the same set of winning conditions against the $\omega$ strategy, just that they give the same chance of winning: The chance of winning with $k$ is given by (\*), which doesn't depend on $k$, and the limit as $k \to \infty$ of (\*) as an expression is exactly what you write for the probability of winning if you pick $\omega$ if the other players never choose $\omega$, i.e. if $p_\omega = 0$.

Comment: I thought you had claimed that choosing $\omega$ was the same as choosing $1$, but I don't see it.  I have removed that.  I have added an argument that $p_\omega=0$

Comment: That's a nice argument! I think you're right that it works for all higher ordinals: I think the idea is that you can show in general that if $k \leq \ell$ then $p_k \leq p_\ell$ by your argument. Namely, that if you take "no ties" as a prior, then clearly choosing smaller numbers is better; choosing $1$ dominates every other strategy because it's an auto-win. So the only way for this to "balance out" once you allow ties is if choosing smaller numbers leads to a tie more often, i.e., if $p_k \leq p_\ell$ for $k \leq \ell$.

Comment: Yes, that argument came to me last night going to bed.